# Simulate going to url that ends in .php in C#

Tags: c#

How can I simulate visiting a url in chrome that ends in .php. What code is being run exactly?

For example,

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/upload.php");
req.GetResponse();
```

Would the c# code be as simple as this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with php, check msdn for creating a web request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx and set your custom user agent

Comment: I know how to create a webrequest but is this how google chrome does it? When I navigate to a url, is this the code that is run? That is what I'm interested in, sorry if the question suggested otherwise.

Comment: Why dont you just try the code? and compile it.

Comment: @winner_joiner Did you even read my question. I know that above code works but is it the code that is being run when I navigate to a page using a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick.

Set the useragent to the Chrome Useragents: **http://www.useragentstring.com/** you can find different ones

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/upload.php");
    req.UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
    req.GetResponse();
```

**[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx)** you can find the documentation to the property on msdn.

Comment: And then what code is run to actually send the request?